# Is it OK to use emojis/symbols in DynamoDB keys?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, amazon-dynamodb, key, emoji

I'm getting into single-table ddb design and I'm discovering the need for delimiters and other significant characters in the keys themselves.

In order to avoid the possibility of having the delimiter symbol show up in the key value-itself, I'm thinking of using emojis/symbols as delimiters:

```
'parent➡️childType≔{childId}➡️grandchildType≔{grandchildId}'
```

I [read here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html) that dynamo accepts UTF-8, and I [read here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/11/character-sets-encoding-emoji/) that emojis can be UTF-8 encoded. But I'm far from expert on the matter, so, an authoritative answer would be well appreciated : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your text as is in a real DynamoDB table and it works just fine as a key and a value, but personally I would use double colons. So it looks like this:

```
parent::childType=123::grandchildType=456
```

IMO, it is easier to read is why I use them and nothing else uses that.

Whatever you choose, just a small tip. Remember that these characters count as part of the overall size of the item. When it comes to `GetItem`, `Query`, and `Scan` operations the size of the names matters. So, do not go wild here unless it really makes sense.

Comment: If you don't mind expanding just a little bit on "It works" please. Also, how are you comfortable using the `=` char : )

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski I tested it in an actual DynamoDB table as a key and a value and what you are asking about does work.

Comment: I know. I did that too. But, do you think it's enough? Is there a possibility that our special characters might get lost in translation when sending them to Dynamo from our app?

Comment: Depends more on the SDK I would think. DynamoDB itself does not care.

Comment: Sure enough, this came back to bite me : ) https://stackoverflow.com/q/65167158/592641