# How to prevent Safari from implicitly converting character in XHR request?

Tags: string, unicode, safari, char, mobile-safari

I picked this character `〉` as a separator for my combo-key-field for my DynamoDb database.

That character surfaces in the browser as part of a next-page-query token. (in an endless scroll list view)

Chrome properly sends that character to the backend (as part of the next-page-query token).

However, Safari, sends that character as this character: `〉`, which is different, and as a result, my backend is unable to recognise it.

Why is the browser changing the character? Is this behaviour expected? Did I miss declaring a char-set somewhere?

Probably an important finding is that running `'〉' === '〉'` returns `true` in Safari.

wAt?

Comment: It's result of [Unicode normalization](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). For instance, `'〉' == '〉'` in Python returns `False` while `unicodedata.normalize('NFC','〉') == '〉'` is `True`… I don't know if there is a setting for this in Safari (it's answerable at https://superuser.com/ rather).

Comment: @JosefZ thanks. Did I understand correctly? I picked a non-normal non-unicode character, which is why Safari translates that to a normal one. If that's the case, how do I pick from a normalised/unicode set of characters?

Comment: If I can guess that you use `perl` then: [Unicode Normalization Forms](https://perldoc.perl.org/Unicode::Normalize)… You could find similar functions or methods in almost any scripting language.

Comment: @JosefZ go ahead and put this as an answer. There is no other way.